# Position a span at bottom of div unless the div is larger than viewable area of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some HTML like this:

```
<div>
Some content here
<span>content here</span>
</div>
```

The div is `variable height` and can sometimes extend beyond the viewport of the browser.

I'm trying to figure out how to do this in Pure CSS if possible, but possibly jQuery.

```
if(height of div stretches beyond bottom of browser window)
    position span 10 pixels above bottom of browser window
if(height of div doesn't stretch beyond bottom of browser window)
    position span 10 pixels above bottom of div
```

Is there a way to do that with Pure CSS?

Comment: It is hard to give a complete answer without any surrounding HTML. Also I think it would be vary hard if not impossible to do this in CSS purely, I'd suggest using jQuery. Something like `if ($('div').offset().top + $('div').height() > $(window).height())` should work.

Comment: I added it as an answer, is your problem now solved?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code to detect if the div exceeds the window:

```
if ($('div').offset().top + $('div').height() > $(window).height()) {
    // The div exceeds the view of the window
    // Execute your code here
}
else {
    // The div is within the view of the window
    // Execute your other code here
}
```